# Magento 2 : Static blocks with products on category landing page

Tags: magento2, category, product-list, filter, static-block

**I am stuck in a situation here, In Magento 2 Category settings and I wants approaches from you guys**.

In Magento 2 I have created a category with Static blocks with products to show settings on the landing page. The category landing page is coming with static block and products with pagination.There is also layered navigation section on the left sidebar.

**What I want?**

When the user clicks on any filter attribute or pagination link then It should show only filter product list. But it is showing filter product list with the static block.

So, What approach should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can override category view page and add condition there like if filter or pagination parameter is set, don't print static block.